# My docker was stuck by down whalesay, what should I do?

Tags: docker

I am new with docker, and I learn the start with docker, then something went wrong with `docker pull whalesay`: it's to big, and my download was stuck.

My operating system is OS X El Capitan.
Here is my docker version:

```
JocelyndeMacBook-Pro:~ jocelyn$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.3
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 17:56:04 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.3
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 17:56:04 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

From your Mac, simply shutdown the current VM (I suspect it is named default: do a `docker-machine ls` to make sure of its name)

```
docker-machine stop default
```

Then restart:

```
docker-machine start default
docker-machine ssh default
```

And try to pull another image.

---

Note that [issue 12823 "Docker can hang indefinitely waiting for a nonexistant process to pull an image"](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12823) is being addressed by [PR 19743 "Set idle timeouts for HTTP reads and writes in communications with a registry"](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/19743): [commit e23ea05](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/e23ea05e113ea5069f8bea3e75046b9429ca2e75), possibly for docker 1.10 early February.

If the remote size becomes unresponsive for any reason... at least it will now timeout.